# React Native Save captured images and video to custom folder on my device

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I have tried to research for the right answer for me on saving captured images or videos to custom folder on device but have not seen a suitable answers. I have been able to save to my DCIM, but I don't want to save them there, I want to create a custom folder to save my captured images or video from my app. I am new to react native and this is my learning process...

```js
takePicture = async () => {
        if (this.camera) {
          if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            await this.checkAndroidPermission();
          }
            const options = { quality: 1 };
            const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
            //save photo
            CameraRoll.save(data.uri, 'photo').then(onfulfilled => {
                ToastAndroid.show(`VidApp Photos: ${onfulfilled}`, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            }).catch(error => {
                ToastAndroid.show(`${error.message}`, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            });
        }
    };


    recordVideo = async () => {
      if (this.camera) {
          if (!this.state.recording)
              this.startRecording();
          else this.stopRecording();
      }
  }

  startRecording = async () => {
    this.setState({ recording: true });
    this.countRecordTime = setInterval(() => this.setState({ seconds: this.state.seconds + 1 }), 1000);
    const cameraConfig = { maxDuration: this.state.maxDuration };
    const data = await this.camera.recordAsync(cameraConfig);
    this.setState({ recording: false });
    CameraRoll.save(data.uri, 'video').then(onfulfilled => {
        ToastAndroid.show(`VidApp Videos: ${onfulfilled}`, ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }).catch(error => ToastAndroid.show(`${error.message}`, ToastAndroid.SHORT));
}

stopRecording = () => {
    this.camera.stopRecording();
    clearInterval(this.countRecordTime);
    this.setState({ seconds: 0 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the album parameter of CameraRoll.save

```
CameraRoll.save(data.uri, {type:'photo',album:'CustomFolder'});
```

from the docs

> It allows to specify a particular album you want to store the asset to
> when the param album is provided. On Android, if no album is provided,
> DCIM directory is used, otherwise PICTURE or MOVIES directory is used
> depending on the type provided.

Comment: It still saving to DCIM, and not saving to CustomFolder

Comment: can you try CameraRoll.save(data.uri, {type:'photo',album:'CustomFolder'}); ?

Comment: Oh yeah...super excited it worked, thanks Guruparan. I don't know if I should create a new question or I should still ask the question here...there's still a lot I want to achieve with my test app...I want to retrieve the images into my app as gallery with thumbnails: I want to be able to share and delete picture...please I still need help here. Thanks.

Comment: i've updated the answer, hope you can mark it, as its a whole different thing better if you create a new question :)